# Cokin a-series or p-series filters for 52mm filter thread lenses?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters

I want to buy some ND grad filters but am unsure whether to purchase the Cokin a-series or p-series. I prefer smaller and lighter equipment because it is easier to transport and since my lenses (18-55mm and 55-200mm) both have a 52mm filter thread, is there any disadvantage to buying into the a-series rather than the larger p-series?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 18mm focal length of your wider lens would show the filter holder in the frame, if you used the A-series. Cokin themselves only [recommend](http://www.cokin.co.uk/pages/cokinA.htm) using the A series for 36mm focal lengths and above, but if you're using a cropped sensor camera you could probably get away with 24mm. Even the P-series are [recommended](http://www.cokin.co.uk/pages/cokinP.htm) for 28mm and longer, but again that would probably be more like 18mm on a cropped sensor, so you may just get away with it.

The P-series filters and holders aren't really too cumbersome, and even if you are restricted from using the wider end of your 18-55mm zoom, that would be less of an inconvenience than having to lug around and pay for the very expensive X-Pro or Z-Pro series.

Comment: I use the Cokin P system (albeit by a different manufacturer) with my 18-55 and the holder doesn't show even at the wide end (that's on a DX format camera).